# JW Player vs FlowPlayer

Tags: flash, rtmp

I am considering using either JW Player or FlowPlayer as the core of our playback for a streaming/video content application.

Requirements:

- Handle high stream volume (10,000+ concurrent viewers)
- Low resource usage (end user)
- Ability to work with prerolled ads
- Customizable interface
- Open source
- High definition playback

Optional (preferable):

- Mobile player (iPhones, Android)
- HTML5 support

Both are comparable in price and features.

Which of these is best? Any other player that is worthy of mention?

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure which is the best, though I'd look at flowplayer first.  Flowplayer has support for pre-rolled ads build in where for JWPlayer it's plugin that you must purchase.  Now JWPlayer might be worth the money but at least with Flowplayer you can start at no cost.

Answer (score 0):

also JWPlayer is not Open source - if that's important for you, you have to resort to FlowPlayer.

Update: JW Player's source is available indeed, so you could say it's open source but it is for sure not "Free Software" (and "Open Source" is commonly used as synonym to Free Software even if there are well-known individuals/groups who dislike that).

> The JW Player is free for non-commerical use.  To buy a license for commercial use, please
>   visit ...

Source: http://developer.longtailvideo.com/svn/tags/mediaplayer-5.9/README.txt

Free Software requires the ability to use the code without any restriction (freedom 0 - http://www.gnu.org/philosophy/free-sw.en.html)

Comment: Byron: I think you are wrong unless you resort to a very limited definition of Open Source. I'm happy to be wrong though - can you point out how JW Player's license is free software?

Comment: It is a fundamental misconception to think that Open Source means Free Software. Open Source means the source code is freely available - this in no way means that it is free to use for a given purpose; that will depend on the software's license.

Answer (score 0):

Also with jwPlayer you need to pay to remove the watermark. With FlowPlayer this isnt the case.

Comment: You actually have to renew the license every year to keep using JW Player without watermark. FlowPlayer has paid version, but it is one time payment. Basic paid versions of both players cost the same, but with JW Player you have to pay for it every year.

Answer (score 0):

I am using Jw Player since v4 and its best for me, you can find source code on github.